# How to set variable type? TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, variables, typeerror

I've looked at many similar issues but cannot find an answer so I'm hoping you guys can help me.  I keep getting that `TypeError` message but have no idea why.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
number = raw_input("Enter a number to be rounded: ")

decimallocation = number.find('.')
right = number[decimallocation:]    
greater = int(number+right+1)
lesser = int(number+right)

if right >= .5:
    print (greater)
else:
    print (lesser)
```

Comment: Looks like your `right` is a string, so it can't be compared with a float. Perhaps do `if float(right) >= .5:`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is this line:

```
greater = int(number+right+1)
```

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
greater = int(number+right) + 1
```

One more possible error is in checking:

```
right > .5
```

where right is a `str` but `.5` is not

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
greater=int(int(number)+int(right)+1)
lesser=int(int(number)+int(right))
```

You need to make sure everything you are adding is an `int` or a `str`, you cant add both types together.